# One to many relationship in M2

Tags: magento2, collection, model, query, resource-model

I am working on a module where I have to implement one to many relationship. I have one table for series with `id and name` field and one table series_product where I have `id, series_id, product_id` and I want to make relation in models like we do in MVC. can we implement this on model??

Comment: You want  multiple table relation via single model?

Comment: I want If I delete record in series table then it should automatically deletes from series_product tables as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want delete the record in **series** table then it should automatically deletes from series_product tables as well then you need to work at model class  &  resource model class of `series` table.

**Add  `afterDeleteCommit`at Model class and add below code:**

```
   public function afterDeleteCommit()
    {
        $this->getResource()->deleteSeries($this->getId())
        parent::afterDeleteCommit();
    }
```

**Then on Resource class of series table  define deleteSeries**

```
  public function deleteSeries($series_id)
    {
        $this->getConnection()->delete( $this->getTable('series_product'), ['series_id = ?' => $series_id]);
        return $this;
    }
```